# how to count the database record using the timestamp in h2 (I need record for the latest 5 minutes)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, h2, sql-timestamp

I am new to the H2 database. How to query H2 database to get the records of a specific column for the last five minutes?
I have tried something like this,it doesn't work..

```
select count(*) from SAMPLE.LOG where LOCKED_UTC > sys_extract_utc(systimestamp - (interval '5' minute))
```

where SAMPLE is the schema and LOG is a column

The format of LOCKED_UTC looks like this:  27-MAY-16 07.40.11.585000000 PM